# php pdo two nealry similar selects

Tags: php, pdo

I´m trying to get uses to the PHP PDO Syntax. Maybe somone can have a look at this peace of code. It seems it´s a bit much lines for little effort.

I catch a User Post-Input (ID). Know I need for calculation reason the values BejagFlach from all Users (the sum of them) and the single value BejagFlach from the User identified by the ID. Do I need two querys for this like here? or is there are shorter/better way?

```
/* Fetch POST Data */
$User_Num = $_POST['User_Num'];

/* Build query for one User */
$dbSelect =  $objDb->prepare("SELECT BejagFlach,Name FROM Benutzer WHERE lfdNr = :User_Num");
$dbSelect -> setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
$dbSelect->execute(array(':User_Num' => $User_Num));

/* Build query for all Users */
$dbSelect2 =  $objDb->prepare("SELECT BejagFlach FROM Benutzer");
$dbSelect2 -> setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
$dbSelect2->execute();

/* Output + Calculate */    
while($row = $dbSelect->fetch()) {  
    $totalUser +=  $row['BejagFlach'];
    $who = utf8_encode($row['Name']);
}  

/* Output + Calculate */    
while($row = $dbSelect2->fetch()) {  
    $totalAll += $row['BejagFlach'];
}
```

Kind regards, 
toni

Comment: The query containing `WHERE lfdNr = :User_Num` matches exactly 1 or 0 records, not more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need at least your second query, I would do like this so you do only 1request to the database :

```
$dbSelect =  $objDb->prepare("SELECT BejagFlach,lfdNr FROM Benutzer");
$dbSelect -> setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
$dbSelect ->execute();
while($row = $dbSelect->fetch()) {  
    $totalAll +=  $row['BejagFlach'];
    if( $row['lfdNr'] == $UserNom) {
        $totalUser += $row['BejagFlach'];
        $who = utf8_encode($row['Name']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't seem too much?

The only thing I would change, is if you are only after the number of records matched, use [rowCount](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

```
<?php
    $sel = $dbh->prepare('select * FROM fruit');
    $sel->execute();

    /* Return number of rows that were deleted */
    print("Return number of rows that were selected:\n");
    $count = $sel->rowCount();
    print("Seleted $count rows.\n");
?>
```

Comment: Or $sel = $dbh->prepare('select count(*) FROM fruit');

Comment: @timmalos Yes, but you might not want to run an expensive query (the query might takes seconds to return) just to get a row count, then do it again to get the results. This will get you the results the first time, and you will be able to see how many rows you have before you do anything with them.